# error in install.package("phia")

Tags: r, install.packages

I am running macOS High Sierra: 10.13.3 and RStudio: 1.1.383
I am trying to install the package "phia" to use the interactionMeans
I have tried changing my mirror to no avail
However, I get this error;

```
> install.packages("phia", repos="http://cran.r-project.org", 
  dependencies = T)
  also installing the dependencies ‘rio’, ‘car’


  There are binary versions available but the source versions are 
  later:
  binary source needs_compilation
  rio  0.5.5 0.5.10             FALSE
  car  2.1-6  3.0-0             FALSE

  trying URL 'http://cran.r- 
  project.org/bin/macosx/mavericks/contrib/3.3/phia_0.2-1.tgz'
  Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 570570 bytes (557 KB)
  ==================================================
  downloaded 557 KB


  The downloaded binary packages are in /var/fo 
  lders/73/gmd2dyv53bq9z861m7x1v09h0000gn/T//Rtmp23hrdR/downloaded_pa      
  ckages
  installing the source packages ‘rio’, ‘car’

  trying URL 'http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/rio_0.5.10.tar.gz'
  Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 70117 bytes (68 KB)
  ==================================================
  downloaded 68 KB

  trying URL 'http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/car_3.0-0.tar.gz'
  Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 443887 bytes (433 KB)
  ==================================================
  downloaded 433 KB

  * installing *source* package ‘rio’ ...
  ** package ‘rio’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
  ** R
  ** inst
  ** preparing package for lazy loading
  Error : object ‘read_xls’ is not exported by 'namespace:readxl'
  ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘rio’
  * removing             
  ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/rio’
  Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rio’ had non-zero exit status
  ERROR: dependency ‘rio’ is not available for package ‘car’
  * removing       
  ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/car’
  Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘car’ had non-zero exit status

  The downloaded source packages are in
‘/private/var/folders/73/gmd2dyv53bq9z861m7x1v09h0000gn/T/Rtmp23hrdR/downloaded_packages’
```

If anyone has any ideas please fire them at me!

Comment: Can you try installing `readxl` (i.e. `install.packages("readxl")`) *prior* to executing `install.packages("phia", repos="http://cran.r-project.org", 
  dependencies = T)` again?

Comment: @mauritsevers that worked, thank you